# showing 404 error while deploying my Servlets progra

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, http-status-code-404

My Servlets program

```
package com.srccode.example;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;


public class  Jaan implements Servlet{  
ServletConfig config=null;  

public void init(ServletConfig config){  
this.config=config;  
System.out.println("servlet is initialized");  
}  

public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)  
throws IOException,ServletException{  

res.setContentType("text/html");  

PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();  
out.print("<html><body>");  
out.print("<b>hello simple servlet</b>");  
out.print("</body></html>");  

}  
public void destroy(){System.out.println("servlet is destroyed");}  
public ServletConfig getServletConfig(){return config;}  
public String getServletInfo(){return "copyright 2007-1010";}  

}
```

**Update:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HelloWorldServlets</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

while deploying this program on Tomcat server it showing 404 error why? Is there is any wrong in my code.404 error in browser screenshot is -->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuPuy.png. Resolve this problem

Comment: First look at Servlet Container's[Tomcat] logs to verify if this servlet is registered in a web context and any issue on loading this servlet. Better to provide web.xml and its folder structure as well.

Comment: create proper web.xml file and deploy war file on server.For sample  web.xml see here http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric53/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.9/getting-started/tutwebapp-web-xml-file.html

Comment: @ chandpriyankara my question is updated  with `WEB.XML`see and tell me what the wrong

Comment: @ Raju see my  WEB.XML once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not configured your web.xml with your Servlet.

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Jaan</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Jaan</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.srccode.example.Jaan</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jaan</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Jaan</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I edit in XML and saved that and then started server but still am getting same error.why?

Comment: What is the url you are using to access the servlet?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlets/WEB-INF/classes/com/srccode/example/Jaan`.java this is the url

Comment: Please understand that nothing under WEB-INF is served. You should use the url http://localhost:8080/yourAppName/Jaan

Comment: my name is `HelloWorldServlets`

Comment: while running tomcat it only shows in web browser like `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlets/WEB-INF/classes/com/srccode/example/Ja‌​an`

Comment: @ Prasad Kharkar r u there..?

Comment: @servletsram sorry buddy I was disconnected. Did it solve your problem? I see you have accepted the answer.

Comment: sorry me also disconnected.pls try to help me ...i need ur help

Comment: @ Prasad Kharkar help me.i need ur help

Comment: still my problem persisting me

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.xml.

```
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jaan</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.srccode.example.Jaan</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jaan</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Jaan</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

This will map URL -> `localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlets/Jaan` to your servlet `Jaan`